# script parameter containing spaces invoking mediainfo

Tags: quoting, whitespace, bash-expansion

I'd like to create a small shell script that will tell me the duration of a video whose file name is passed to it as a parameter. It'd be something like this:

```
$ script_name "file name with spaces.webm" # or any other media file extension
```

The script file would resemble

```
#/bin/bash
SECRET_SAUCE_USING_$1 | mediainfo | grep Duration | sort -u
# maybe SECRET_SAUCE_USING_$1 | xargs -0 mediainfo . . .
```

On the command line, this is what works and what I want the script to do:

```
$ mediainfo file\ name\ with\ spaces.webm | grep Duration | sort -u
```

I've tried using things like

```
echo "$1" | sed 's/ /\\ /g' # piped to mediainfo . . .
```

to change the spaces in the file name to '\ ' character pairs (without the quotes). The echo ... | sed ... part works but mediainfo barfs

and

```
echo "$1" | tr ' ' '\000' | xargs -0 mediainfo . . .
```

to change the spaces to nulls and get xargs to invoke mediainfo with nulls in the file name instead of spaces.

I haven't found a solution so far. (I actually use zsh, not bash.) All help greatly appreciated. Tnx.

Comment: `mediainfo '--Inform=Video;%Duration/String4%\n' "$1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the script's parameter (`$1`) to end up as mediainfo's parameter, then just put it there:

```
# ...
mediainfo "$1" | grep Duration | sort -u
# ...
```

That works for a single parameter to the script. More flexibly, you could loop over all of the script's parameters and feed them one at a time to mediainfo:

```
for file in "$@"
do
  mediainfo "$file" # ...
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was the very first thing I tried and it didn't work when I originally tried it. Now it does. I must have been doing something wrong before. How do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: Happy to hear! Looks like you found the check mark, so you’re all set!